# Debugging Error occur while uploading android app on google play

Tags: android, debugging, google-play

I am submitting my APP to GOOGLE PLAY, while uploading Google show error that i should OFF debugging in order to upload my app, kindly help me out, i don't know how to OFF debugging.

Answer (score 0):

in your manifest file paste this

```
<application
    android:name="@string/app_name"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:debuggable="false"        
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
```

and also the tips from @danidee will get you set..